# How to generate iid samples from the linear congruent method?

Tags: monte-carlo

Given a uniform random number generator (such as [the linear congruent method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator)), how shall I generate a sequence of i.i.d. random
    samples?

Are samples generated in a successive sequence i.i.d., or
    are they just realization of a single random variable (i.i.d. is for
    several random variables, and therefore doesn't apply to samples of
    a single random variable?)?

Given a seed, we can get a sequence of points. Can these points be taken as iid uniform samples? 
I don't think they are independent, because each point can be determined by the previous point as
$$
    X_{n+1} \equiv \left( a X_n + c \right)~~\pmod{m}.
$$

If you also don't think they are independent, how do you generate iid samples from the linear congruent method then?

If you think they can be good approximation to independence, why?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, they're not really iid--there's an obvious serial correlation!

I think actual answer to your problem is that linear congurential generators are pretty lousy ways of generating random numbers and, unless you're in some situation where memory is **exceedingly** tight, you  may be better off using something more modern. The Mersenne Twister algorithm is pretty popular for Monte Carlo simulations. It's somewhat more complicated than an add + mod operation, but it's not unduely complicated and state size is still pretty small.

Comment: Thanks! (1) My question is not just for LCG, but for any method that starts with a seed and generate a predictable sequence. If I understand correctly from Wikipedia, MT algorithm also falls into that category? (2) Given a seed, is it acceptable to use the predictable sequence generated by such kind of methods as iid samples? What is common practices to generate iid samples from a uniform random generator?

Comment: (3) "Proposition 2.8 (Daniell)" on page 4 of http://math.iisc.ernet.in/~manju/ProbTheory/Notes/1-3%20Independence.pdf gives a way for constructing i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables defined from [0,1] to {0,1}, by using binary expansion, which are rigorously iid. Is that way used commonly in Monte Carlo simulation for generating independent samples?

Comment: 1) MT is also predictable if you observe enough sequential inputs, but given its much larger state, it's vastly better than a simple LCG. 2) I'd say MT is usually considered good enough for Monte Carlo simulations, but not good enough for cryptography 3) Those propositions show you how to transform various types of random variables into others (e.g., to transform a single random number into a sequence of random variables or vice versa). It's probably similar to how R or Python produce numbers drawn for various distributions.